# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error when using iterator?

Tags: java

Why am I getting this problem when trying to print it out? What I'm trying to do is display out the name that was placed in the array.

```
    ArrayList <Employee> empArray = new ArrayList();
    LinkedList empyrIncm = new LinkedList();
    ListIterator li = empyrIncm.listIterator();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#, ##0.00");

for (int i = 0; i<empArray.size(); i++)
    {
        double yrIncm = empArray.get(i).getSalary() * 12;

        if (yrIncm > 80000)
        {
            empyrIncm.add (new String (empArray.get(i).getEmpName()));

            while(li.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println ("\nName : " + li.next() + "\nTotal yearly income : " + df.format (yrIncm));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foundyrIncm = false;
        }
    }
```

From what I know, the iterator I used is to display out the name "one-by-one" without the "comma" when more input are added to the array. Means, without the use of iterator, it will display out by default

```
Name : Object1, Object 2, Object 3, Object 4 
Total yearly income : 123
```

I don't want that comma, instead I want the name to be display out one by one with their yearly income. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're adding elements to the list while iterating on it. That's what causes the exception.

Comment: Either avoid doing the insert and read at the same time of make sure to synchronize the list so you can't do concurrent things on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do following two line's activity together i.e.read & write together with regular fail-fast iterator data structures :-

```
empyrIncm.add (new String (empArray.get(i).getEmpName()));
while(li.hasNext())
```

If you want to do both read & write together then do either of the following :-

```
empyrIncm.add (new String (empArray.get(i).getEmpName()));
ListIterator li = empyrIncm.listIterator();
while(li.hasNext())
```

OR

Use **CopyOnWriteArrayList** instead of LinkedList/ArrayList.

Now if you try to print any list then default implementation provided by API prints all element in list by comma seperated, hence the output you getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding element to the list here:

```
empyrIncm.add (new String (empArray.get(i).getEmpName()));
```

while you are iterating the list here:

```
System.out.println ("\nName : " + li.next() + "\nTotal yearly income : " + df.format (yrIncm));
```

The iterator in java are Fail-fast. It will not allow you to update the list while iterating over it.

You need to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`. Normally `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is very expensive because it involves costly Array copy with every write operation. Use the below statement.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList empyrIncm = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
```

Also your `iterator` getting call will be postponed until you need it. Just before the `while` loop.

```
ListIterator li = empyrIncm.listIterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the `ListIterator` just outside the while loop.

```
ArrayList <Employee> empArray = new ArrayList();
LinkedList empyrIncm = new LinkedList();
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#, ##0.00");

for (int i = 0; i<empArray.size(); i++)
{
    double yrIncm = empArray.get(i).getSalary() * 12;

    if (yrIncm > 80000)
    {
        empyrIncm.add (new String (empArray.get(i).getEmpName()));

        ListIterator li = empyrIncm.listIterator();
        while(li.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println ("\nName : " + li.next() + "\nTotal yearly income : " + df.format (yrIncm));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foundyrIncm = false;
    }
}
```